# Multiple links in magento admin panel stopped working

Tags: magento

I am having a strange issue. Was using magento admin area and suddenly the records listing pages like Catalog or Static blocks had no more links to edit any product or static block respectively. If I select "edit" link under Catalog listing, the next page opens but only left side tabs appear and right side is blank.

While inspecting I noticed that some javascript files are not being loaded and returning 404 error, while these files do exist in the directory. See the screenshot. Any help will be appreciated. Using magento 1.9.1.0

Also on server I see this error message
client denied by server configuration: /home1/royalse7/public_html/app/etc/local.xml

[Javascript files not being loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5V4U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Request to take backup to do anything further.
Then

Flush all magento caches.
Delete everything inside var folder.

Also there is a chance to have problem in your magento code that you are installed your magento.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found .htaccess file in mage/js/ folder that had some external links to an other hosting service. Seems like it was a hack attempt. Fortunately I am safe.